# Modify $\tan(x)$ function to output $\infty$ with each step equals $1$

Tags: trigonometry

$\tan(x)$ outputs go from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ with each step equals $\pi$

My question is how to modify or build a function based on $\tan(x)$ that outputs of the function will change from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ with a step of $1$ instead of $\pi$?

Comment: $\tan(\pi x){}{}$

Comment: @T.Bongers wow so fast, thanks. Can you please explain why $\tan(\pi x)$ behave like that?

Comment: If all you want is a monotonically increasing function that diverges to $\pm\infty$ when $x$ approaches $\pm 1$, then $\frac{x}{1-x^2}$ is simpler to compute.

Comment: Because given a function $f(x)$, if you want to contract it by a factor of $\dfrac{1}{a}$, you need to multiply $x$ by $a$. You wanted to go from a period of $\pi$ to 1. That is a factor of $\dfrac{1}{\pi}$. So, you need $f(\pi x)$.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe thanks for explain

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks. I will give it a try. I'm finding a function that have stated properties but also have big enough derivative.

Comment: $ y =\tan ( 2 \pi x/ P) $ which reduces to $y= \tan \pi x$  for period $P=2.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You noticed that those individual curves between the asymptotes (where y = tan(x) approaches $\infty$ from one side a $-\infty$ from the other) each cover a horizontal distance of $\pi$.

This is called the period of the function.  $y = \tan x$ has a period of $\pi$.  (And $y = \sin x$ and $y = \cos x$ both have a period of $2\pi$.)

In general, if you have periodic function $y = f(x)$ with a period $p$, the function $y = f(Bx)$ will have a period of $\omega = \frac p B$.

Since $y = \tan(x)$ has a period of $\pi$, to find the value of $B$ such that
$y = \tan(Bx)$ has a period of 1, take the formula $\omega = \frac p B$ and plug in 1 for the desired period $\omega$, a $\pi$ for the period of $y = \tan(x)$ and solve for $B$.

$1 = \frac \pi B$ will pretty clearly give you $pi$ for B.

Therefore, $y = \tan (\pi x)$ will have a period of 1.